# Need help on implementing loop in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in my SQL Server database `FACULTY_RECORDS` & `SCHOOL_RECORDS`. I have rows containing data filled by faculties about the lectures they took in the table `FACULTY_RECORDS` and rows containing time slots allotted by school to faculties for conducting lectures on their subjects.

The faculty fills up his/her lecture start time in format '10:15:00' in the column `LECTURE_START_TIME` in table `FACULTY_RECORDS` and school mentions the time slot in format '0900-1200' provided to faculty in the column `LECTURE_TIME_SLOT` in table `SCHOOL_RECORDS`.

Now, I have a SQL query which check if the time entered by faculty for his particular subject falls in the time slot allotted by the school or not. However, with the SQL query I am getting multiple output rows because the same start time falls in multiple time slots. Whereas, I require the query to to provide only one output if the lecture start time falls in the time slot allotted for same subject.

Please see my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    a.FACULTY, 
    a.SUBJECT, 
    a.LECTURE_DATE, 
    a.LECTURE_START_TIME 
FROM
    (SELECT
         b.LECTURE_TIME_SLOT, b.FACULTY, b.SUBJECT, b.LECTURE_DATE, 
         CAST(LEFT(b.LECTURE_TIME_SLOT, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(b.LECTURE_TIME_SLOT, 4), 2) AS TIME) AS StartHours,
         CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(b.LECTURE_TIME_SLOT, 4), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(b.LECTURE_TIME_SLOT, 2) AS TIME) AS EndHours 
     FROM 
         @FACULTY_RECORDS AS a, @SCHOOL_RECORDS AS b) AS b 
JOIN
    @FACULTY_RECORDS AS a ON a.FACULTY = b.FACULTY 
                          AND a.SUBJECT = b.SUBJECT 
                          AND a.LECTURE_DATE = b.LECTURE_DATE 
WHERE
    CAST(a.LECTURE_START_TIME AS TIME) >= b.StartHours 
    AND CAST(a.LECTURE_START_TIME AS TIME) <= b.EndHours
```

Please refer to below images:

[FACULTY_RECORDS & SCHOOL_RECORDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cXyQ.jpg)

[Outputs: Lectures not matching & matching the time slots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt09D.jpg)

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server. Which are you using?

Comment: I am sorry. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and not mysql.

Comment: can this be useful for you? https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/sql-server-loop-over-a-table/

Comment: Hi Piero, thank you for the url provided. I will try to modify the sql query into sql script to check if it works.

Comment: If the lecture start time falls within two timeslots... _which timeslot do you want_ do you want to arbitrarily not show one? The reason you get multiple output rows is because mutliple rows match the criteria. You need to think pf some rules to pick just one of those. The easiest and hackiest solution is to pick the first time it matches. But what about the second time that it matches? That's a valid match also. What is your report actually trying to show?

Comment: the best way forward is to provide "sample data" and "expected result"

Comment: If one 'LECTURE_START_TIME' value is found matching with multiple 'LECTURE_TIME_SLOT' values, then I need only that particular 'LECTURE_START_TIME' from 'FACULTY_RECORDS' table appearing once in my output. With the current query, I am getting one 'LECTURE_START_TIME' multiple times in output. I facing issues uploading images of "sample data". I will upload them soon.

Comment: Generally I would suggest using `EXISTS` instead of a join in this case but  I will make an effort to assist only if you make any effort to explain the full case and post sample data.

Comment: I have uploaded the images in my question above. Kindly refer to them. In output, I have mentioned two tables (one having rows matching the time slots and other having rows not matching the time slots)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear why you are using an implied cross join (Cartesian product) of the 2 tables. It really would help if there was sample data and the expected result. In the absence of those, does this help?

```
select
     f.SUBJECT
   , f.LECTURE_DATE
   , f.LECTURE_START_TIME
   , s.StartTime
   , s.EndTime
FROM FACUTLY_RECORDS f
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
             SUBJECT
           , LECTURE_DATE
           ,  CAST(LEFT(LECTURE_TIME_SLOT, 2) 
                 + ':' 
                 + substring(LECTURE_TIME_SLOT, 3, 2) AS time) AS StartTime
           , CAST(substring(LECTURE_TIME_SLOT, 6,2)
                 + ':' 
                 + RIGHT(LECTURE_TIME_SLOT, 2) AS time) AS EndTime
        FROM SCHOOL_RECORDS
      ) s  ON f.subject = s.subject
           AND f.LECTURE_DATE = s.LECTURE_DATE
           AND CAST(f.LECTURE_START_TIME AS time) BETWEEN s.StartTime AND s.EndTime
 ;
```

Here is an alternative approach which does NOT use conversion to time. It does not fail trying to convert '26:10:00' to time. It only lists matches from both tables as it uses an inner join.

```
SELECT
      f.SUBJECT
    , f.LECTURE_DATE
    , f.LECTURE_START_TIME
    , s.StartTime
    , s.EndTime
FROM FACUTLY_RECORDS f
      INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  SUBJECT
                , LECTURE_DATE
                , LEFT(LECTURE_TIME_SLOT, 4) AS StartTime
                , RIGHT(LECTURE_TIME_SLOT, 4) AS EndTime
            FROM SCHOOL_RECORDS
      ) s ON f.subject = s.subject
                  AND f.LECTURE_DATE = s.LECTURE_DATE
                  AND replace(left(f.LECTURE_START_TIME,5),':','') BETWEEN s.StartTime AND s.EndTime
;
```

I would suggest you provide more complete test data, and of course the expected result which is still absent.

[image: queries]

```
CREATE TABLE FACULTY_RECORDS
    ([FACULTY_NAME] varchar(4), [SUBJECT] varchar(7), [LECTURE_DATE] datetime, [LECTURE_START_TIME] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO FACULTY_RECORDS
    ([FACULTY_NAME], [SUBJECT], [LECTURE_DATE], [LECTURE_START_TIME])
VALUES
    ('Alex', 'Biology', '2015-01-10 00:00:00', '3:55:36'),
    ('Alex', 'Biology', '2015-01-10 00:00:00', '10:7:22'),
    ('Alex', 'Biology', '2015-01-10 00:00:00', '11:17:44')
;

CREATE TABLE SCHOOL_RECORDS
    ([FACULTY_NAME] varchar(4), [SUBJECT] varchar(7), [LECTURE_DATE] datetime, [LECTURE_TIME_SLOT] varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO SCHOOL_RECORDS
    ([FACULTY_NAME], [SUBJECT], [LECTURE_DATE], [LECTURE_TIME_SLOT])
VALUES
    ('Alex', 'Biology', '2015-01-10 00:00:00', '0900-1200'),
    ('Alex', 'Biology', '2015-01-10 00:00:00', '0900-1200'),
    ('Alex', 'Biology', '2015-01-10 00:00:00', '0900-1200')
;
```

Comment: Hi, this query is not working. I purposely changed a value for 'LECTURE_START_TIME' as (26:10:00) and it was checked against 'LECTURE_TIME_SLOT' value (0900-2400). I could see the value '26:10:00' in the output of above query. Ideally, it should not reflect in my output. I guess the 'BETWEEN' clause is not working?

Comment: I again purposely changed a value for 'LECTURE_START_TIME' as (03:10:00) and it was checked against 'LECTURE_TIME_SLOT' value (0900-2400). I could see the value '03:10:00' in the output of above query. Ideally, it should not reflect in my output. For this row with the start time '03:10:00' StartTime and EndTime value generated by query is 'NULL'

Comment: Use an innér j oin instead of a left outer join. I will amend the answer foo

Comment: The reason you keep finding fault with my suggsted query is because you are slowly revealing more data and more requirements. If the test cases of 'LECTURE_START_TIME' as (26:10:00)  & (03:10:00) were available in the question AND you showed or stated they should not be in the result - then I would know more about what it is you need. That is why supply of sample data and the expected result is so important.

Comment: This is the number one reason I spend most of my time on here commenting instead of posting answers. To ascertain the OP's commitment to the question

Comment: I have uploaded the sample data and output required. I am extremely sorry for the delay.

Comment: You want me to retype that data? sigh. I really do thank you for trying - but when you do your next question make the sample data text that you paste into your question.

Comment: You have 2 output requirements (you didn't state that in your original question) but should be able to use the first of my suggestions above to produce the matched rows (i.e. with the inner join). For the unmatched rows, use a LEFT JOIN and then add a WHERE s.SUBJECT IS NULL.

Comment: Sorry, I was travelling and hence uploaded the pictures. Next time on wards I will put the sample data in text format.